# scala io throws error while reading a file

Tags: scala

When i try to read a file using scala it is not working , but in this location i have file

Is this permission issue

```
scala> val loc =  "C:\\Users\\gvenk\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Input\\accountdetails.txt"
 loc: String = C:\Users\gvenk\OneDrive\Desktop\Input\accountdetails.txt

 scala> Source.fromFile(loc, "UTF-8").getLines().toList
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\gvenk\OneDrive\Desktop\Input\accountdetails.txt (The 
 system cannot find the file specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStr
```

Comment: Is it somehow `Source.fromFile`-specific? Does `(new java.io.File(loc)).exists()` also say that it exists?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is in the error message: `The system cannot find the file specified`. This means either the file doesn't exist or misspelled something.